# I'm trying to get JFrame to work, but it keeps popping up with a error saying "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to get into learning JFrames and I was just following a tutorial, when I was done and tried running VS code said my build failed and then came up with the error "Could not find or load main class"

```
    import javax.swing
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.plaf.DimensionUIResource;

import java.awt.*;

public class wagwag {
    
    private static void woah(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("simple GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel text = new JLabel("I am the label", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        woah();
    }
}
```

There's the whole code that I have written down. I know that the naming is dumb, but I just wanted to see if I could get JFrame to actually work lol.

Comment: The first import line is wrong. You need `import javax.swing.*;`

Comment: *"There's the whole code"* No, it apparently [is *not* the whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAHeB.png). Run-time errors don't occur in code that will not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

"Could not find or load main class" indicates that it can not find a class that contains your "public static void main (String[] args) {...}" in your case this is because you have not ended your import statement. Thus your IDE thinks you are still importing

On line 1  you have the following:

```
import javax.swing
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.plaf.DimensionUIResource;
```

This should be replaced with the below notice the ".*;" at the end

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.plaf.DimensionUIResource;
```